# Complete Recompile when Changes in Model

Tags: playframework

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.4 with Hibernate as ORM (as described here https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA). When I do changes in the code of a model without changing the API (e.g. a new blank line) the entire project is recompiled. This is rather annoying and as I understand the framework not the intention of the compile-process of Play. Is this behaviour normal for model changes or may be the cause the integration of hibernate?

Comment: Are you sure it recompiles the entire project? If you change a source file Play will recompile it, no matter if you just added a newline or changed the source code...

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It compiles the exact same amount of classes like when I do a clean and compile.

Comment: Did You resolve this?